# How to disabled encode "&" in my select options

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to pass a multiple space character in my options select. This is for make different select level because HTML allowed just one level (optgroup). It's not a good practice but it's not my decision.

So, i have this form builder:

```
->add('buttonAddresseInt', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'testText' => 'Classical text',
                    'testGroup' => array(
                        'test1' => 'test1',
                        'test2' => ' &nbsp; &nbsp;test2',
                    ),
                ),
```

The problem is a `&nbsp` character present in test2 key. Because in twig the character `&` is encode in HTML and display `"&amp;nbsp;"` I try disabled encode in twig but without effect :

```
{% autoescape false %}
     {{ form_widget(accueilEditForm.buttonAddresseInt)|raw  }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

[image]

In resume, i need this result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the output as safe. You can do this with a `Twig_Markup`:

```
->add('buttonAddresseInt', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'testText' => 'Classical text',
                    'testGroup' => array(
                        'test1' => 'test1',
                        'test2' => new \Twig_Markup(' &nbsp; &nbsp;test2', 'UTF-8'),
                    ),
            ),
```

Comment: Sorry but this solution doesn't work.
Maybe she work with simple var... I maybe found a solution with form template, but i stay open to your proposition !